# Flutter - How to Merge Two Stream in Flutter ? Why I'a getting Only Last Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to Merge two Firestore Stream in a Futter. I have tried so many ways But in some cases, I got an error and others only return the last stream, not the merged Stream. This is my code

```
class Classes extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClassesState createState() => _ClassesState();
}

class _ClassesState extends State<Classes> {
  String path0 = "class_schedule/Classes";
  String path1 = "users/R2z6mt5/Classes";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Rx.merge([
            Firestore.instance.collection(path1).snapshots(),
            Firestore.instance.collection(path0).snapshots()
          ]),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return !snapshot.hasData
                ? Text('PLease Wait')
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot items = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          height: 50,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              items['Course'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Please Tell My How can I Solve this Issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: *"I got an error"* - i dont see any error

Comment: @pskink I want to Merge But It Only show Last Stream.

Comment: what *error* you got? what do you see in the logs?

Comment: @pskink Not in Rx.merge if I use StreamZip then I got "Class 'List<QuerySnapshot>' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: documents
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I use StreamZip then I got "Class 'List' has no instance getter 'documents'. Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList' Tried calling: documents "

It is because when you merge with StreamZip, every stream event will be A list,
for example if 2 streams A and B which emit `int`, merging them with StreamZip will emit `List<int>` of length 2, at index 0 will be the event of Stream A and at index 1 will be the event of Stream B, So you need to access them like `zippedStreamEvent[0].docs` and `zippedStreamEvent[1].docs`

let me give you a code sample

```
StreamBuilder<List<QuerySnapshot>>(
    stream: yourZippedStream,
    builder: (_, snap) {
      if(!snap.hasData){
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      final allDocs = [...snap.data[0].docs, snap.data[1].docs];
      return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (_, i) {
        final doc = allDocs[i];
        return YourListWidget();
      });
    },
  );
```

Comment: Can Tell me How To I implement this on my code. If you can It will be Helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/async) to merge two streams together. See documentation for better understanding.

Comment: StreamZip ?? I was tried Its not works for me

Comment: make sure to add async to your dependencies

Comment: Yeah. Thanks This Library Works for me @lenz

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/StreamZip-class.html), `StreamZip`:

> [E]mits lists of collected values from each input stream. The first list
> contains the first value emitted by each stream, the second contains
> the second value, and so on.

Hence, the type of `snapshot.data` in your code is `List<QuerySnapshot>`, which obviously doesn't have a `documents` getter. You would access the first `QuerySnapshot` like this: `snapshot.data[0]`, then call `documents` on that. Similarly, the second would be `snapshot.data[1]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks It Works for me @Riwen